# Understanding the instance variable names and the methods to create it using Spring @Bean annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lambda, functional-interface

I have written a simple Spring Boot Application, which I would later extend to build a Spring REST client. I have a working code; I have tried to change a few instance variable names and method names and playing around.

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestClientApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestClientApplication.class, args);

    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            RestClientApplication.class)) {
        System.out.println(" Getting RestTemplateBuilder : " + ctx.getBean("restTemplateBuilder"));
        System.out.println(" Getting RestTemplate : " + ctx.getBean("restTemplate"));
    }
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.build();
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner runner() {
    return args -> { SOP("hello"); }
}

}
```

**Observations:**

1. The instance variable names follow the camel-case notation, as
   expected. So, restTemplate and restTemplateBuilder works.
2. While creating a RestTemplate instance through restTemplate() method, I tried changing the name of the argument to builder. It works.
3. While creating a RestTemplate instance through restTemplate() method, I tried changing the name of the method to a random one and I get an exception that "No bean named 'restTemplate' available".
4. CommandLineRunner interface is implemented through a lambda expression. Accessing commandLineRunner throws an exception.

**Question**

Why do I see the results mentioned in point #2 and #3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While creating a RestTemplate instance through restTemplate() method,
>   I tried changing the name of the argument to builder. It works.

This works because, By default spring autowire's by type. So it searches for a bean with type `RestTemplateBuilder` and it finds it and hence no error.

> While creating a RestTemplate instance through restTemplate() method,
>   I tried changing the name of the method to a random one and I get an
>   exception that "No bean named 'restTemplate' available".

You are getting an exception not because you changed the method name, but because of this

```
ctx.getBean("restTemplate")
```

Because by default `@Bean` uses method name as name of the bean. ([check this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html)). So the name of the bean of type RestTemplate which is returned by your random method is name of your random method. Hence when you try to get a bean with name `restTemplate`, it throws exception.

But if you were to Autowire a bean of type RestTemplate, it would still work, because Spring will Autowire by type by default and it knows a bean of type RestTemplate(name as random method name).

Comment: Thank you so much. I have added point #4 too related to this code. Kindly answer that.

Comment: I have basic idea about Spring core, Spring context and DI. Can you please provide me references for the reasoning to grasp such concepts.

Comment: best way is to try different things and find out answers why is it working so. Not sure if you can learn everything ny reading docs. But if you want to read spring docs are a great place to start with

Comment: I get why #4 works so. Accessing it as 'run' worked.

Comment: `@Bean(name = "restTemplate")` If you annotate bean like this you can give any name there but still the object will be `restTemplate` @sara

Comment: @Sara can you show the code how your are printing. I feel its better to create another question. For people who are seeking similar help, So many details in comments doesn't really help

Comment: @SumeshTG So, the name parameter taken precedence over the method name. That is true, I just verified.

Comment: @pvpkiran will do so. In the meanwhile, I am just printing the object name.

Comment: @Sara how are you invoking the SOP inside the CommandLineRunner bean?

Comment: @pvpkiran Created a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098453/two-different-hash-codes-for-an-object-created-through-spring-boot-in-the-same-c